Should I Capitalize This?
In story I wrote, I mentioned the time I worked at

Attorney General's Chambers

in Nairobi. Should the 'c' in chambers be capitalized or not?

Please [edit] this question to tell us what you already understand about capitalization, what you have done to answer this question yourself, what you found, and what you're still unsure about.

If the name of the organisation is "Attorney General's Chambers" than you would capitalise it.  For example, one of the administrative divisions of the government in St Lucia is called "The Attorney General's Chambers" It is parallel to "The Ministry of Health" or "The Supreme Court".  The names of these places (ministry and court) are likewise capitalised.
However if the name of the organisation isn't "Attorney General's Chambers", and this is just a description, then use "chambers".  I believe the official name in Kenya is "The Office of the Attorney General and the Department of Justice", and "chambers" is just a common noun, and not capitalised.
But this is a point that you should probably not worry too much about. There is clearly a subtle point, and most people won't know if it is an "official" name or not. So it won't affect readability. People just won't notice it.

It's the sort of thing I was paid to notice, but then I worked in a building called Albion Chambers and wrote/read about matters occuring in rooms described as  judges' chambers.

We should follow the actual proper noun. I found two versions, and both use the capital 'C'.
Other than that capitalisation, as there are two versions, we should check before using them.
Attorney-General's Chambers
Attorney General Chambers
